# How can I become a better Connect Four player?

Tags: connect-four

I am good player at Connect Four and I want to become better.

One [suggestion](http://boardgames.about.com/od/strategygames/a/How-To-Win-At-Connect-4.htm) I found is:

> The ideal position is to have two potential connect-fours that need a final checker on two spaces that are on top of each other. This will usually lead to a victory, because you can threaten in the first space. If the opponent fails to block, you win. If the opponent blocks, you play on top to win in the next space. A simple way to set this up is to make a "7" with your checkers, such that finishing the horizontal or diagonal connect-four on the right will be two spaces on top of each other.

Are there any other tips for improving my Connect Four play?

Comment: Your last paragraph is literally word-for-word from the last suggestion at this website http://boardgames.about.com/od/strategygames/a/How-To-Win-At-Connect-4.htm. You should site any sources you use in your question.

Comment: Is it possible to become better at playing a [solved game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solved_game)?

Comment: @Tacroy, Yes, by actually learning the solution & then remembering it at game time.

Comment: @Tacroy - Of course. Just because it's been solved doesn't mean that *you've* solved it (or can solve it), or that your opponent has perfect play.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Connect 4 is a solved game.  Memorize the solution, and you should be able to win every single time.

Go to the following resource

http://www.connectfour.net/Files/connect4.pdf

I came to that link from [The Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect_Four), so in case the link ever breaks, you should be able to find another by searching for the `"connect 4 solution"`

That article has a lot of strategic analysis about connect 4, and Even if you can't memorize the solved strategy perfectly, you should be able to glean a lot of good strategic practices from section 3 which is titled `Some Strategic Rules for Connect-Four`

Comment: Yes, the link has become outdated.

Answer (score -4):

Control center column immediately when you can. Generally if you can control the 2 very center slot then you are in a very very good position to win.